# get an entry from Infinispan cache without affecting last modify timestamp

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

Is there a way to examine an entry in a cache (`org.infinispan.Cache` implementations) without affecting expiration policy?

Meaning, if I have configured `maxIdle`, the results of the cache operation won't affect the time the entry is going to be evicted?

Something such as `Ehcache` `Cache.getQuiet(Object key)`.

If calling `cache.containsKey`, does it have effect on idleness?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In regards to lifespan, accessing the entry from the cache doesn't affect this.  Only maxIdle is affected by an access.

`cache.containsKey` will affect max idle and it will be refreshed.

The only way to not update idleness is by iterating over the entries or accessing the entry through the DataContainer directly using peek (shown here).

```
DataContainer<K, V> container = cache.getAdvancedCache().getDataContainer();
InternalCacheEntry<K, V> entry = container.peek(key);
```

Note that this may not work properly with a distributed cache, since accessing the data container only reads local contents.  Although it is also mentioned that max idle shouldn't be used in a clustered cache [here](http://blog.infinispan.org/2015/10/expiration-enhancements.html), as it is not guaranteed to refresh idleness across cluster.